# Customizar Swipe JS centralizado e aparecendo outros elementos

Tags: javascript, css

Preciso de uma ajuda.

Estou usando framework7, e consequentemente o SwipeJS em um template no qual preciso deixa-lo mais ou menos assim, (App duolingo). com os cards em baixo e sempre o próximo e anterior aparecendo um pouquinho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz algumas alterações na CSS e estrutura do HTML, mas nenhuma que me desse essa solução para deixar os cards da maneira desejada :(

O código é simples... Disponibilizei o mesmo no codepen:

http://codepen.io/henriqueweiand/pen/ZWeWJQ/?editors=1010

Alguem tem alguma dica?

Obrigado

Comment: Seria excelente ter o HTML que estás a usar e um exemplo do que já conseguiste. Assim como está não é bem claro para mim o que precisas. Pode ser que outros percebam melhor.

Comment: Olá! Humm, ok... Atualizei o post. Veja se agora esta mais "intendivel" :P